# MariaDB either not allowing host to connect or access denied for user

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, mariadb

I have a Laravel project working fine on my local machine, but unable to connect to database on another Linux server.

The error I get is:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'cpanel1_thewatcher'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

These are the settings I am using:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dbnamehere
DB_USERNAME=cpanel1_thewatcher
DB_PASSWORD=passwordhere
```

I have checked to make sure `cpanel1_thewatcher` has `ALL PRIVILEGES` on this database and that the password is correct.

This is on a VPS, where I have root access, and it has two IPs dedicated to it. The main IP we will call xxx.xxx.xx.165 and the second one xxx.xxx.xx.166. If I change the settings above to set `DB_HOST` to xxx.xxx.xx.166 I get a different error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'xxx.xxx.xx.166' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server
```

If I set `DB_HOST` to xxx.xxx.xx.165 then I get yet another error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'cpanel1_thewatcher'@'server1.domain.com'
```

If I set `DB_HOST` to domain.com (the main domain on the server) I get  the same error I get with DB_HOST=xxx.xxx.xx.166.

I have examined the `mysql.user` table on the server and found the following:

```
+-------------------+----------------------+
| User              | Host                 |
+-------------------+----------------------+
| root              | 127.0.0.1            |
| cpanel1            | xxx.xxx.xx.165       |
| cpanel1_thewatcher | xxx.xxx.xx.165       |
| root              | ::1                  |
| cpanel1            | localhost            |
| cpanel1_thewatcher | localhost            |
| nagios            | localhost            |
| root              | localhost            |
| cpanel1            | server1.domain.com |
| cpanel1_thewatcher | server1.domain.com |
| root              | server1.domain.com |
+-------------------+----------------------+
```

- where `cpanel1` is the username of the only cPanel account on the server.

I have tried creating an entry in the table above where user is `cpanel1_thewatcher` and host is `%` but no effect. I have also tried setting `DB_USERNAME` to just `thewatcher` but nothing changes in the error messages.

I have seen some questions on SO referring to the second error message I listed, but I have been unable to find a MariaDB configuration file anywhere on my server as suggested by some answers there.

Doing `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbnamehere.* TO 'cpanel1_thewatcher'@'localhost';` gives

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Can anyone tell me what to do, I am confused with the 2 IPs and 3 different error messages here, and not sure what else to try. I'd like to eliminate any issues on my end before I resort to contacting the hosting company and waiting for a week for them to resolve it.

Comment: How did you check the password is correct?

Comment: I removed the database and user and then recreated everything with the dbname, username and password from the env file. Same messages remained.

Comment: have you done GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ... on your user with server1.domain.com / xxx.xxx.xx.165   too ?

Comment: What do you get for `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'cpanel1_thewatcher'@'localhost';`?

Comment: Do you have skip-name-resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow this steps in order to connect to your remote database:

> In your database server, run the following command in your `mariadb` console:

```
CREATE USER 'cpanel1_thewatcher'@'xxx.xxx.xx.166';
```

> Followed by:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbnamehere.* TO 'cpanel1_thewatcher'@'xxx.xxx.xx.166';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

> Where `xxx.xxx.xx.166` is the `ip` of the machine you are trying to connect **(where your `laravel` project lives)**